# Read all lines on file uploaded

Tags: php, edi

I know this subject already exist but in my case is a little more difficult.

I'm reading .EDI files (current succeed) on PHP, the process:

1.- I upload a .edi file from a html form.
2.- I send those attributes  from the form to read on my php code.

I got the code like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['ufile']['name'])){
   $tmpName = $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'];
   $newName = "" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'];   
   if(!is_uploaded_file($tmpName) ||
                        !move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $newName)){
        echo "<table><tr><td><strong>Failed to read file ".$_FILES['ufile']['name']."</strong></td></tr></table>";
   } else {
        echo "<br>";

        //coloca o conteudo do arquivo para a variavel $arquivo         
        $ponteiro = fopen ($_FILES['ufile']['name'],"r");
        $arquivo = '';
        while (!feof ($ponteiro)) {
         $arquivo = $arquivo.fgets($ponteiro,4096);

        }           
        fclose ($ponteiro);
        if (unlink($_FILES['ufile']['name']) != 1) echo "Erro ao deletar arquivo!";         

        $padrao = fnc_resgata_padrao($arquivo);

        if ($padrao == "COARRI"){
            $a = fnc_processa_coarri(trim($arquivo));

            prc_mostra_coarri($a);              
        }
        elseif ($padrao == "CODECO") {
            $a = fnc_processa_codeco(trim($arquivo));
            prc_mostra_codeco($a);              
        }
        else {
            echo "<table><tr><td><strong>Invalid file</strong></td></tr></table>";
        }           

   } 
} else {
     echo "You need to select a file.  Please try again.";
  }
```

The problem is, in this way only read the first line of the .EDI file and not all lines. I'm trying to understand that i must print an array but i don't know how to do it because my `$a` has the values i'm interested.

If the post is hard to understand, please let me know.

**update 1**

I just deleted some lines of the code, nothing important.

Comment: `$i=0; while (!feof ($ponteiro)) {
$i++;
         $arquivo = $arquivo.fgets($ponteiro,4096);`

after that do your checks if $i==1.
if you decide to NOT work with the file because it has an invalid format, simply do break; and close/unlink the file.
else 
simply stay in the feof loop

Comment: In this case of EDI, can read any extension. I will try, i suppose i must check that $i on my "if" where i call the function, am i right?

Comment: PSEUDO CODE:
set $i=0;
read line of file as long as there is another line in the file;
$i++;
check if $i==1
true: get $padrao = fnc_resgata_padrao($arquivo);
Now your following checks (like if ($padrao == "COARRI"){ ) or a break; if you want o skip the file.

if you don't think that this helps you, please describe as easy as possible what you want to do.

Like: 
Read file line by line
If it's the first line check with some functions for something
else just do other stuff
and so on

Comment: Part of the pseudo code has sense but as you said, i need to read the file line by line, the problem is when the file is uploaded, it only reads the array on the position 0 (cero) and when i do var_dump only shows position 0. This function is who handle the file, the rest of the function manage the data that is already readed.